# Smallness/ Rigidity of $\kappa(\mathcal{H})$ without using minimal projections?

Tags: banach-spaces, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space and $\kappa(\mathcal{H})$ the $C^*$-algebra of compact operators on $\mathcal{H}$. By smallness/ rigidity of $\kappa(\mathcal{H})$ I am referring to the following collection facts about $\kappa(\mathcal{H})$.

> Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a $C^*$-subalgebra of $\kappa(\mathcal{H})$. If $\mathcal{A}$ is irreducible then $\mathcal{A}=\kappa(\mathcal{H})$.
>
> The only closed ideals in $\kappa(\mathcal{H})$ are $\{0\}$ and $\kappa(\mathcal{H})$.
>
> Let $\mathcal{B}$ be a $C^*$-algebra in $\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H})$. If $\mathcal{B}\cap\kappa(\mathcal{H})$ is non-trivial, then $\mathcal{B}\supset\kappa(\mathcal{H})$.

$\kappa(\mathcal{H})$ is so small that it cannot contain proper irreducible $C^*$-algebras, or proper ideals; and it only *touches* those $C^*$-algebras that fully contain itself.

Also we have the following facts about representations of $\kappa(\mathcal{H})$:

> Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a $C^*$-algebra in $\kappa(\mathcal{H})$. Each nondegenerate representation of $\mathcal{A}$ is the sum of orthogonal irreducible representations that are equivalent to the identity representation.

And in particular,

> The only irreducible representation of $\kappa(\mathcal{H})$ is the identity.

These are describing the very rigid structure of $\kappa(\mathcal{H})$.

In all the books I read, the proof of these series of facts is based on the notion of minimal projections, in particular the following

> Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a $C^*$-subalgebra of $\kappa(\mathcal{H})$. A projection $E$ in $\mathcal{A}$ is minimal if and only if $E\mathcal{A}E=\mathbb{C}E$.

This line of argument seems standard now and indeed it is very clever and clear. But it is also a little tricky at least to me. So I wonder whether we can prove these facts independent of minimal projections (or at least try to hide them to the backstage). If this can be done, then I really hope to see the proof (a sketch or some references would be enough). If this cannot be done, then I'd like to know the reason.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just saw your question and I think I can introduce a reference for one of the above statements. The fact that $K(H)$ is simple is proved in Corollary 5.7.6 of my lecture notes on $C^*$-algebras available at arXiv:1211.3404. The proof rests on the facts that $K(H)$ is the closure of the ideal of finite rank operators and this latter ideal is contained in every non-zero ideal of $B(H)$.